# Custom environment variable name restriction in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pdfbox

We are deploying a Java SE application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which uses PDFBox for pdf rendering.

Since there are some issues with the redering performance in Java8, PDFBox FAQ recommends setting the system property:
-Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider OR
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");

I created the property with a config file in .ebextensions, I can see it in the environment configuration section, but I can't get it in the JVM. When I perform System.getProperty("sun.java2d.cmm") the value is null.

AWS support told me that "sun_java2d_cmm" works, which is correct, but I need this specific parameter not the version named with "_".

Does anybody know why this limitation exists and if there is another solution for my problem?

Regards,
Cristian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS technical support will be investigating this issue but there is a chance that it's a technical limitation which can't be overcome. However, a fix can be implemented by using a procfile and starting the app from there:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-procfile